# Is it reasonable to buy a new Apple Watch even though you own an iPhone 8?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I own an iPhone 8 and I am considering buying an Apple Watch SE (GPS, 44 mm). I have had my iPhone for a long time and I have replaced the battery once. In my opinion, the iPhone 8 works perfectly well. But I have been contemplating about getting a fitness watch for a long time now and I really wanna buy an Apple Watch, but is it a good idea? Will it not drain my phone battery when paired? And will all features on the watch be available?

> Question: Should you buy an older Apple Watch if you own an iPhone 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone 8 supports iOS 14 which is compatible with watchOS 7, the latest OS available. Therefore all the features of the new watch will be available without compromise compared to a new iPhone.

Your iPhone battery will not have any noticeable impact caused by an Apple Watch. Bluetooth is required for phone/watch  communication, which can use some small amount battery on any phone, and may be more of an impact on an older phone with worse battery life due to age.

Comment: As to the battery, I recently upgraded to iOS 14 on my iPhone and using a Fitbit. I noticed the battery dropped significantly to under 50% sometimes below 25% by the time I went to sleep. After switching to the Apple Watch, my battery has been around 70%. Your mileage will vary, of course.